# Ionic 4 problem with cordova-android@8.0.0, with Ionic serve works fine, but on device the screen just goes blank

Tags: android, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I had a problem with the **firebase plugin** on ionic 4 the app just didn’t compile and I had to upgrade **cordova-android@7** to **android@8.0.0** the app compiled, but for the start just brank, there is Ionic info.

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.2.3 (C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.3.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.8
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.3.8
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.9
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.5.1

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.0.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.0.1, (and 18 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.6.0
   native-run  : 0.2.8

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v10.16.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.9.0
   OS                : Windows 10
```

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1):

Solved my problem by updating an all Cordova plugins

1- install that tool in your project
`npm install -g cordova-plugin-update`

2- when done you then have to run the command
`cordova-plugin-update`

that will ask you if you want to update each plugin.
it solved my problem with **cordova CLI 9** and **cordova-android@8.0.0**

I believe that the problem was with the plugin `cordova-plugin-ionic-webview` that was outdated for `cordova-android@8.0.0`